# Failed - Network error downloading my Google Takeout

Tags: download, google-takeout

I am trying to download my 35GB Google Takeout .tgz file but it keeps failing part way through.

- On Chrome I might get about 3 GB progress, then it reports `Failed - Network error`.  I have tried several times.

[image: partial and failed attempts]

- On Firefox, I manged about 75% of the file downloaded on the one attempt.

My internet is pretty stable and I haven't had problems downloading relatively large ISO images, but I couldn't be sure that my connection would be 100% glitch free for the 3 hours it takes to download.

I'm considering generating a .ZIP takeout instead, but then I have to manually download lots of 2GB zips.

Got any better ideas?

Answer (score 5):

If you are familiar with linux/unix then there is a simpler method using wget/curl.

Steps:

- Initiate download via takeout page in your browser
- Go to "Window->Downloads"
- Locate the download which is in-progress right now
- Right click + Copy link address
- From your terminal - wget {url}

wget is more stable. you can manually set timeouts.

Bonus: you can initiate this from a remote server. I have seen speeds upto 250 MBps from remote servers. Just be sure not to cancel the browser download before your wget finishes.

Comment: Thanks! As of 04/2022 this still works. :)
I would recommend using [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) if you are using wget on a remote server through ssh.

Comment: I would also add the use of wget this way `wget -O customname "url"` as wget, in my case, did not use the file name and just part of the url as the filename (which makes it hard to identify which file is which).

Comment: Thanks for this idea. What makes you believe that wget is more stable than a browser? I'm hopeful you're right, because my Google Takeout downloads in Brave keep failing, and then Google annoyingly expires the entire export after a certain number of attempts. Also, what is the benefit of setting timeouts, and what would you recommend? Thanks.  @daco thanks for the suggestion because `wget` wasn't working when I just supplied the (really long) URL. I didn't realize that you meant "customname" as a placeholder, so I think my file is being saved as "customname".

Comment: And would retries be a useful option? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/227666/48973

Comment: @Ryan I’m happy it worked for you. If you saved your file as “customname”, you just have to rename it to the name you want plus the right extension.  For example if you chose a zip file as the export option, rename “customfile” to “newName.zip”.  With screen and whet on a computer which was always in (No suspend options in energize settings) and connected to internet by cable (not by wifi) I downloaded around 170gb without problem.  I tried the same using Firefox and safari on a MacBook and a Linux laptop without success.

Comment: @daco Good to hear. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, if you have the free legacy Google suite and want to take a takeout of all your data (and that of your Users) ist it easier to use gcloud. The Trick is to activate 2 factor auth for the admin User.  If this is not activated the option is not available.

Comment: @Ryan :) by the way, I just remembered this is what I used https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/557109and it could be interesting for you.  Is from this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557102/how-to-resume-download-in-wget-for-google-takeout-data

Comment: @daco Thanks so much for the tip!! I will try https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install-sdk#deb and https://stackoverflow.com/a/71119171/470749

Comment: Coming back to this answer today to +1 and confirm that all of my `wget` Takeout downloads worked in WSL Ubuntu (after I set my power settings to stay awake permanently). Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on what you want to do.  If you are looking to backup your Google account and want it uploaded to another Google account, then I would just say pay for [g-transfer](https://www.g-transfer.com) because there should be no problem moving a large amount--this is what I ended up doing.

If you want to export to a hard drive, then you can try the `.zip` method, you can download your drive files individually, or maybe even try using Takeout in Chrome if you're not doing that already.

Comment: Hi Debra.  I notice that you and perhaps a few of your colleagues are promoting this product in various answers.  While it does provide an answer the questions in most cases, we tend to frown upon these subtle promotions of products, particularly when a pattern arises.  I would ask that you disclose any affiliation with the product in your answer and refrain from using answers as a means of promotion.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use aria2c!

1. Open up the Developer Tools, then click the download link.
2. View the Network tab and identify the request, likely it will come from a googleapis.com subdomain.
3. Right click the request and Copy request location.
4. Click on the Headers tab and in the Request Headers section, locate the line beginning with Cookie:.
5. Combine all of the information you now have into a download command with aria2 like so:

   aria2c -o export.mbox -c --header="Cookie: AUTH_e2e0q...etc" long-request-url-goes-here

Source: https://kylekelly.com/posts/2014/12/04/google-takeout-with-aria.html